# How to use temp tables in SQL Server to display the days of the week

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I am trying to do the following: I know there are probably other ways to do this, but temp tables must be used.

I believe what I am supposed to do is make a temp table that displays each day of the week and next to it the amount of books sold so far for the week. Please let me know if you think the question wants something else. Even after reading up on temp tables I still have no idea how they work.

The tables I have in the database are:

- Authors
- Books
- Categories
- BookCategories
- Customers
- Orders
- OrderLine
- OrderStatus

I guess you can assume what kind of fields fill these tables.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the `DATEPART(dw,SalesDate)` TSQL function.

Comment: `create table #DaysOfWeek(DayOfWeek date)`
`insert into #DaysOfWeek(DayOfWeek)`
`values (datepart(dw,))`

`select * from #DaysOfWeek`

`drop table #DaysOfWeek`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide the columns, so this is a guess. Is this what you are looking for?

```
select DATENAME(weekday, Orders.OrderDate) as [weekday], Orders.OrderDate as [Date], Category.Description as Category, Authors.State, isnull(SUM(OrderLine.Quantity),0) as [NumberSold]
into #booksales
from Books
Left Outer join OrderLine
on Books.BookID = OrderLine.BookID
Join Orders
on Orders.OrderID=OrderLine.OrderID
Join Authors
on Books.AuthorID = Authors.AuthorID
Join Category
on Books.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID
WHERE Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN @begindate AND @enddate
GROUP BY DATENAME(weekday, Orders.OrderDate), Orders.OrderDate, Category.Description, Authors.State
```

This assumes you have variables of DATE type that are set to the beginning and ending date of the week.

Comment: Hmm, I fixed this up and it almost seems to work. I am not sure how to declare my variables though.

Comment: DECLARE @begindate DATE='4/7/2013',@enddate DATE='4/12/2013'. If the query solves your problem, can you mark it as answered?